# WebAssembly Error While trying to run NextJs App

Tags: next.js

i have a dedicated server on namecheap, I have node v20.11.1 and npm 10.5.0 installed on it, i am using the default command given on the nextjs documentation page to create a nextjs app through terminal, it gets created without any error but when i use 'npm run dev' to run the app in the terminal it gives me the error below

```
undefined:9988
      return await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, {
                               ^

RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
    at lazyllhttp (eval at requireWithFakeGlobalScope (/home/*****/prosale.cloud/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/load.js:65:3), <anonymous>:9988:32)

Node.js v20.11.1
```

Is there anyone who can help me with it ?

NOTE: I dont know where to start looking to solve this issue, i have searched google and stackoverflow, but I cant seem to find any solution for it